# How to solve integral with rational function of exponential functions using Residue Theorem?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, exponential-function, residue-calculus

How to calculate the following integral of an exponential function:

$$I = \int_{0}^{\infty}{
\frac{e^{-ax}}{1-e^{-bx}}
}dx,$$

with Residue Theorem? Is the Residue Theorem needed here? In textbooks, one often example of a residue integral with exponentials is this one:

$$I = \int_{0}^{\infty}{
\frac{e^{x}}{1+e^{ax}}
}dx = \frac{\pi}{\alpha \sin \frac{\pi}{\alpha}}.$$

This one has a pole in -1, and the upper one in +1, so can it be useful to solve them both via residuals? Or some other kind of method would be better here. Perhaps partial integration or something else. Thank you.

Comment: **Hint** After bounding the integrand in the first integral to show convergence, you can use

$$\frac{1}{1-e^{-bx}} = \sum_{k} e^{-kbx}$$

Comment: Your first integral has a non-integrable singularity at 0 (behaves like $1/x$). Also, as  integral goes from 0 there is no obvious closed contour that seems to bring residue calculus into play?

Comment: The second integral also goes from 0 and has a nice contour that can be used to solve it: http://www.st-andrews.ac.uk/~md90/PH3066/Asmar%205.3.pdf (example 3 gives the solution). I thought that something similar can be used in the first integral, unless the -1 pole in the denominator is a big problem.